# PHPUnit - How to test if callback gets called?

Tags: php, callback, phpunit

Given the following method:

```
public function foo($callback) {
    call_user_func($callback);
}
```

How would I test that the callback actually got called, using PHPUnit?  The `foo()` method has no return value.  Its only job is to execute a callback given to it, with some other lookups and misc. processing that I've left out for simplicity's sake.

I tried something like this:

```
public method testFoo() {
    $test = $this;
    $this->obj->foo(function() use ($test) {
        $test->pass();
    });
    $this->fail();
}
```

...but apparently there's no `pass()` method, so this doesn't work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To test if something was invoked or not you need to create a [mock test double](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html) and configure it to expect to be called N number of times.

Here's a solution for using an object callback (untested):

```
public method testFoo() {
  $test = $this;

  $mock = $this->getMock('stdClass', array('myCallBack'));
  $mock->expects($this->once())
    ->method('myCallBack')
    ->will($this->returnValue(true));

  $this->obj->foo(array($mock, 'myCallBack'));
}
```

PHPUnit will automatically fail the test if `$mock->myCallBack()` is never invoked, or invoked more than once.

I used `stdClass` and its method `myCallBack()` because I'm not sure if you can mock global functions like the one in your example. I might be wrong about that.

Comment: Thanks!  This works great.  I left out the `will()` call, since the callback doesn't actually need to do anything.

Answer (score 9):

You can have your callback set a local variable and assert that it was set.

```
public function testFoo() {
    $called = false;
    $this->obj->foo(function() use (&$called) {
        $called = true;
    });
    self::assertTrue($called, 'Callback should be called');
}
```

Comment: Very simply and effective. Thank you!